# Removing Duplicates using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

I'm trying to remove duplicate rows in my Excel Sheet using Visual Basic. The problem is that the amount of Rows will be variable.

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()
   Range("A1").Select
   ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, ActiveCell.CurrentRegion).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

The problem here is that `Columns:=Array(1, 2)` isn't a variable. It should always look from column `1` until the last filled column (the `.CurrentRegion`).

Can someone please help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to create the array dynamically.

Once the block has been defined, we know exactly how many columns the block contains:

```
Sub luxation()
    Dim A1 As Range, rng As Range, cCount As Long
    Set A1 = Range("A1")
    Set rng = A1.CurrentRegion

    cCount = rng.Columns.Count - 1
    ReDim ary(0 To cCount)

    For i = 0 To cCount
        ary(i) = i + 1
    Next i

    rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(ary), Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

Note the encapsulation of `ary()` in the last line!

Comment: It's interesting how the parenthesis cause the array to be passed ByVal.   I had given up on my answer till I saw that you and Shai Rado used them.  Kudos

Answer (score 2):

Gary's Student has the correct answer.

I'm just having a little fun:

```
Dim a As Variant
With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    a = Evaluate("Transpose(Row(1:" & .Columns.Count & "))")
    ReDim Preserve a(0 To UBound(a) - 1)
    .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(a), Header:=xlYes
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()

   Dim LastCol  As Long
   Dim LastRow  As Long
   Dim ColArray As Variant
   Dim i As Long

   ' modify "Sheet1" to your sheet's name
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        ' find last column with data in first row ("header" row)
        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        ' find last row with data in column "A"
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        ReDim ColArray(0 To LastCol - 1)
        For i = 0 To UBound(ColArray)
            ColArray(i) = i + 1
        Next i

        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(ColArray), Header:=xlYes    
    End With

End Sub
```